# Re-indexing array from 0 in the string

Tags: java

How could I transform this structure in Java? (they are request parameters, so both of param:value are strings)

```
"country[0].town[11].name"="London"
"country[0].town[2].name"="Slough"
"country[2].town[3].name"="New York"
"country[3].name"="UK"
```

to sequential order without gaps like this:

```
"country[0].town[1].name"="London"
"country[0].town[0].name"="Slough"
"country[1].town[0].name"="New York"
"country[2].name"="UK"
```

The idea is that all country array elements would be from [0..x] without gaps. Then in each country the same rule should apply for towns.

I can sort the list of these parameters by Alpha-Numeric order so it can be assumed that they are sorted

The story why I might need this: I can create/delete country objects and towns in html form.  If I create 2 countries and then delete the first one input parameter(index) of the remaining country would be 1 since 0 is deleted. when it goes to server side, this country is being mapped to list index 1 and for the first (index) it creates empty country object. It gives me problems and I thought I could rearrange the order of the input parameters so I could avoid "blank" list items automatically bound from request.

How I generate inputs:

when I delete town I delete inputs as well. So when I submit a form, whatever is in request parameters is bound to the java objects structure and what is missing is populated with the elements with default constructor.

Comment: I don't understand your desired output

Comment: You will have to parse all the strings into some sort of data structure (a `Map` unless you can use bean-like classes) and then output the strings from this data structure.

Comment: if you have country[1] country[7]  country[9] as Strings It should be changed to country[0] country[1] country[2]. Same goes when you go deeper inside.

Comment: I can sort them. You can assume they are sorted

Comment: Why are representing your data as Strings?  You did say that they're request parameters, but that doesn't mean you can't parse them into something trivial to work with.  It would be fairly easy to do with the data you've shown but if you have control over the client it might be even easier to just change the format to something that Java can parse for you (ie JSON or XML)

Comment: if `country[0]` is a `String` then how could `country[0].town[11]` have any legal meaning?  Anyway, if your question is how to write code that takes an array and returns an array that has the null elements squeezed out, you could do this by adding the non-null elements to an `ArrayList` and then the `toArray` method on the `ArrayList` to return a new array.

Comment: You are going to have to provide an explicit example showing all the values, including the gaps, which I presume are null values (construct a more limited version -- no need to have large gaps). Then show what you want for output.

Comment: @ajb: I can create/delete country objects and towns. If I create 2 countries and then delete the first. Input parameter(index) of the remaining country would be 1 since 0 is deleted. when it goes to server side, this country is being mapped to list index 1 and for the first (index) it creates empty country object. It gives me problems and I thought I could rearrange the order of the input parameters so I could avoid "blank" list items automatically bind from request. But I think it takes more work than I thought

Answer (score 1):

I figured I'd try to get a solution working using regular expressions, since I'm so terrible at them.  This will work if you sort them by lexical ordering first, provided that you don't have any countries without names.

```
public class RegexCountryParser {
    private static final Pattern townPattern    = Pattern
                                                    .compile("country\\[\\d*\\]\\.town\\[\\d*\\]\\.name");
    private static final Pattern countryPattern = Pattern.compile("country\\[\\d*\\]\\.name");
    private List<Country>        countries      = new ArrayList<>();

    public void parse(String param, String value) {
        Matcher countryMatcher = countryPattern.matcher(param);
        Matcher townMatcher = townPattern.matcher(param);
        if (countryMatcher.matches()) {
            countries.add(new Country(value));
        } else if (townMatcher.matches()) {
            countries.get(countries.size() - 1).addTown(new Town(value));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid request parameter");
        }
    }
}

public class Country {
    private String     name;
    private List<Town> towns;

    public Country(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.towns = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addTown(Town town) {
        towns.add(town);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ": " + towns;
    }
}

public class Town {
    private String name;

    public Town(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

It wasn't until I started testing this that I realized you spelled `country` wrong.  Also, this is just me being picky but I hate seeing lists that have non-plural names.

Comment: This is not what I need. I use spring framework and it binds request parameters to object graph for me. so if request parameter is "countries[0].towns[0]" it parses this parameter and using reflection creates new MyBean().getCountries().set(0, new Country().getTowns().set(0, new Town)). Smth like that. The problem I have that if in UI I remove some towns(lets say index =0) and add new town with index=1, at the point of binding framework sets null on the country.getTowns().set(0, null). It causes me issues. So I thought I'll 'normalize' parameters before passing to frameworks binder